# Use of the 2 tslint.json file in Angular 6 Project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, tslint

[image]

What is the significance of two tslint.json(inside src folder) and inside project folder? What is the differnece between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The one in the project folder is your generic TS lint file that applies globally.

The one in the src folder is a project specific TS lint file that extends the other one, allowing you to tweak TS lint settings for the specific project.

Remember with Angular, you can have [multiple projects](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-projects) and you may want slightly different TS lint settings for those projects.

If you only have one project, I think it is fairly safe to delete the TS lint file in the src folder. In the project I am working on we seem to have done just that.